# ruby on rails simple_form_for post to url conditionally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, simple-form, simple-form-for

I want to do something a bit outside of the typical rails conventions and I wanted to hear what you guys think.

I have a `Test` model, with nested `Questions`, and `Question_responses`, and I have a form (using `simple_form_for`) where a user selects answers for the questions in a test. That is all working fine, but I would like to add a `Flag` feature if a test taker thinks a question is bad. Right now, I am using a `link_to` method to take the user to the `flag` controller actions that allow them to create the flag, and I temporarily hold onto the test id variable to take them back to the test. That's all working.

However, as one might see, I am not saving the progress of the test before the user heads over to create a flag - so if you were halfway through a test and flagged a question, you would lose your progress. I have an idea, but I'm not sure if it can work with `simple_form` :

I would post the data to some other action within the `tests_controller`, save it, redirect to the create the `flag`, and then redirect back to the test (in an edit method or something like it), and allow the user to finish the test. This should work, but how would I get the view with the form to post the test data to some other url besides the one specified by the `simple_form_for @test, url:` at the top of the form? Is there a way to conditionally post the data to another url depending on where the user clicked, or override the `:submit` protocol for the simple form button object? I'm really not sure, but I feel like someone has to have done something like this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is new to rails and trying to solve a similar problem, here is what I did.

First, I found that simple_form_for is designed to post to one URL, which is the one that you specify in the arguments in the simple_form_for function. However, you *can* conditionally change the url that the form posts to by doing some logic on the url *before* you call the simple_form_for function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975134/rails-conditional-path-in-form-partial) post).

But, in my case I wanted to post to different URLs dependent upon which "submit" button in the form was clicked. However as I said above, this functionality simply isn't built into simple_form. In theory I guess it would be possible to have a javascript function that would change the html data in the form and update the URL that the form is posting to if the user hovers over a button or something, but that is probably unnecessarily complicated unless you're super familiar with JS (unlike me). Bottom line is, there is an easier way.

However, you *can* change the parameters that are associated with the submit button for the form (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916316/is-there-a-way-to-pass-params-when-clicking-submit-button-in-simple-form-view-in) post). So what I did, and what I would encourage others to do is change the parameters that are associated with a particular button in your form, and then apply the logic as needed in the controller action that the form is being posted to.

In my case, I created two buttons in the form - a button that would submit the test data in the usual fashion and a button for a test submission where the user is redirected to a create a flag. Before I redirect them, I save whatever form data has already been input (inside the tests_controller action). The user is  then redirected over to the flag controller actions, and they can create a flag in the typical rails fashion. After the flag has been created, I redirect them back to the test, but this time in the edit path for the test. The data for the test is reloaded, and the user can continue creating a test.

If anyone would like to see the code for how I did this, please let me know in the comment section and I'll edit this answer!